# JavaFX Text bind to JodaTime DateTime property

Tags: java, datetime, data-binding, javafx-2, jodatime

I've got a simple Text field. I need to bind it to a static instance of JodaTime DateTime property. JodaTime gives me plenty of properties, but I can't figure out the solution.

All I need from the DateTime is the actual time, so I would assume something like:

```
Text clock = new Text();
clock.textProperty().bind(AppController.getSimulationClock().toLocalTime().toString());
```

But yet, `toLocalTime()` returns a String. Then again, if I do try:

```
Text clock = new Text();
clock.textProperty().bind(AppController.getSimulationClock().dayOfMonth());
```

Being `dayOfMonth()` returning an actual property, it still doesn't work.
Just for record, `AppController.getSimulationClock()`  just returns a normal immutable JodaTime DateTime Object.

Netbeans gives me this explanation:

> actual argument org.joda.time.DateTime.Property cannot be converted to ObservableValue by method invocation conversion
>     where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Object declared in interface javafx.beans.property.Property

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime.Property does not implement ObservableValue. The property concepts of JavaFX and JodaTime are incompatible.

Comment: Any other way around it? Just need that Text to change whenever my DateTime object changes... Any ideas?

Comment: Try to call clock.textProperty().bind(new javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper(AppController.getSimulationClock().dayOfMonth(), "AsText")); The bean property AsText is DateTime.Property.getAsText() from org.joda.time.field.AbstractReadableInstantFieldProperty.

Comment: Wait, changes to your DateTime object will not be reflected automatically, so this is of no use. Maybe you can signal JavaFX everytime you change your DateTime object to reretrieve the value.

Comment: What do you mean `signal javaFX` ? Setting (and updating everytime I update DateTime) some new variable, such as a String, and binding to it ?

Comment: javafx.scene.text.Text does contain a StringProperty already. You could call clock.textProperty().setValue(AppController.getSimulationClock().d‌​ayOfMonth().getAsText()) after changing the DateTime object. But that may need a more complex solution because of gui-threading.